# Missing options in Texture Paint's Active Tool and Workspace Settings

Tags: texturing, tools

I am following a tutorial on texture painting, and there is no "Texture" option in the Active Tool and Workspace Settings for Texture Painting.  There is also no Texture Mask, Stroke, Falloff, or Display.  How do I make these active?  I often have trouble activating things in Blender.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the new Blender update, they move the option to the top side, You just have to scroll your mouse wheel over there and the option will be there.

Just[image] found out from the documentation lol.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/tool_settings/mask.html